# add_image_size adds size, but doesn't upload if source resolution is same as resize resolution

Tags: uploads, images

I'm trying to add a new image size of 300x300..

This works, but if the uploaded file is for example 300x300, it doesn't upload the resized image.. You'd say that isn't a problem because the original is the resolution I need, but I get the image later on with:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $meta['background'][0], array(300,300) );
```

And if this image is not there, wordpress fetches another size, which of course is not what I want..

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have added an image size

```
<?php add_image_size( 'test', 300, 300, true ); ?>
```

Uploaded an image of exactly 300 x 300px,

Then got the image

```
<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, array(300,300) );?>
or
<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'test' );?>
```

Works both ways. Maybe you did not define the image size correctly in functions.php

Comment: I also added the size to show itself in the uploader, when I upload an image, all sizes bigger or the same as the uploaded image size are disabled.. I'll try switching of showing them, but I doubt it will help.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should not worry about that. Just upload the image and test if you can get it to show.